# How to recursively revert changes to a subtree in git?

Tags: git, git-revert

A development tree:

```
master
    /subdir1
    /subdir2
    /subdir3
        /subdir3a
        /subdir3b
```

I branched out:

```
my-changes
    /subdir1
    /subdir2
        /subdir3a
        /subdir3b
```

Then I modified many files in all the subdirs and committed the massive changes.

Later I found out that I need to revert the changes in `subdir2` and `subdir3/subdir3b`, but should keep the changes in `subdir1` and `subdir3/subdir3a`.

How do I do that? How to revert changes recursively in selected subdirs up to a certain revision, but keep the changes in the other subdirs?